# Why missing virtual d-tor in g++ does not destroy stack allocated members of derived class?

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I have the following code:

```
struct Message
{
   explicit Message(const std::string& message) : selfMessage(message) {};
   ~Message() { std::cerr << "Message: " << selfMessage << std::endl; }
   const std::string selfMessage;
};

struct Foo
{
   Foo() : fooMessage("Foo") {}
   /// Destructor here is left intentionally non-virtual !!!
   ~Foo() { std::cerr << "~Foo" << std::endl; }

   Message fooMessage;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   Bar() : barMessage("Bar") {}
   ~Bar() { std::cerr << "~Bar" << std::endl; }
   Message barMessage;
};

int main()
{
  std::auto_ptr<Foo> foo(new Bar);
}
```

I expect the following output:

```
Message: Bar
Message: Foo
~Foo()
```

But actually (the code is compiled with `gcc`) does not print `Message: Bar` so as far as I understand `barMessage` is not destructed correctly. Why?

AFAIK non virtual d-tor affects only on the call of dtor of derived class - it will be never called, but what about stack-allocated members of derived class?

Thank you,

P.S. I already know about deprecated `std::auto_ptr<>()` usage :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `delete` on a derived object through a pointer to a base class object then you get *undefined behavior* **unless** the destructor of the base class is declared virtual.

Letting an `std::auto_ptr` templated on a base class go out of scope when it owns a derived class object has the effect of calling delete on a base class pointer type when the actual object is of a derived class type.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, `auto_ptr` calls `delete myPtr` (where `myPtr` is a member
of type `T*`).  Invoking `delete` where the static type and the dynamic
type are not the same is undefined behavior.  It's not just a case where
the derived class destructors will not be called; it's a case where just
about anything can happen.  And does, in cases of more complex
inheritance hierarchies.

This is only relevant for dynamically allocated instances.  Invoking
delete on something which wasn't dynamically allocated is undefined
behavior (and will typically cause all sorts of problems).  And except
for delete, the destructor is called on an object, not a pointer, so the
static type and the dynamic type are identical.

Answer (score 1):

`Bar::barMessage` is not destructed precisely because the destructos of the base is not virtual. The pointer is of type `Foo`, and on exiting of the scope, the `std::auto_ptr` dill call `delete` on the internal pointer, which is Undefined behavior, and in this case will destroy only the `Foo` subobject.

Note that there is no such thing as *stack* allocated members of `Bar`, there are members with automatic storage, but in this case as the whole object has been dynamically allocated, that is not in the stack but in the heap (C++ technically has no concept of stack/heap but understand that all the `Bar` object is dynamically allocated)